# Ansible jinja if statement in list and check correct value

Tags: list, ansible, jinja2

I wanto to check if site variable exist on inventory, if there is not exist, I print error message. I find to print value, so I want to check if newyork or paris value are written correclty.

variable file

```
server:
  server1:
    name: server1
    site: newyork
    serie: "[100,200,300]"
    
  server2:
    name: server2
    site: paris
    serie: "[0,1,2]"

server3:
        name: server2
        site: madrid
        serie: "[0,1,2]"
```

task.yml

```
- name: template file
  template:
    src: "toto/toto.j2"
    dest: "/tmp/toto_{{ item.value.name }}"
  with_dict: "{{ server }}"
```

toto/toto.j2

```
    the {{ item.value.name }}
    {% if ("{{ item.value.site }}" == "newyork") or ("{{ item.value.site }}" == "paris") %}
    {{ item.value.site }} = {{ item.value.serie }}
  {% endif %}
```

I think to try with if statement, if paris and newyork is written correctly. but the if statement is always false. how to solve it ?

but how to print a error message and check value on inventory, if someone write madrid for instance. I just want to accept paris and nework value.

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you want, item.value,  value doesnt exist and i dont understant the role of your j2 files.... could you precise with a good sample....{% if {{ item.value.site }} in {{ item.value.site }} %}  ..?????  when you write serie: "[100,200,300]"   ist string not a list of int...or you want serie: [100,200,300]  ?

Comment: `inventory/hosts` doesn't look like a valid inventory file. Or is it a vars file, if so how do you load it? What error does it show?

Comment: sorry it is a variable file, no inventory. I don't have any error, but I want to verify is paris and newyork values are correctly written. For instance, if someone write London, I have got an error.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"**If someone write London, I have got an error**"*

A: Test the site is in the dictionary, e.g. given `my_site=London`

```yaml
    - fail:
      when: my_site not in server|json_query('*[].site')
```

you'll get the error

```yaml
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: Failed as requested from task
```

Comment: thanks for your replying, it answer the half question. I edit the question, I try the if statement, if newyork or paris exist. but the jinja code, diqplay nothing and the comparaison is always false

Comment: but London is an example, how check for any value exept newyork or paris ? because, it would be London, Madrid, Barcelone... is is not only London but multiple value. Thanks

Comment: Only ``newyork`` and ``paris`` are in the dictionary. It's is checking ``for any value except newyork or paris``, actualy.

Comment: indeed, but on task.yml you define variable my_site, and it is not a generic value

Comment: I'll be more than happy to use the generic value and the variable if you provide one. [edit] your question and make it [mre].

Answer (score 0):

From the description in your question, and your comments - it appears that you don't want the template to be created for the server if the `item.value.site` does not match `newyork` or `paris`.

For this, we can do a comparison such as: `item.value.site in ["newyork", "paris"]`.

You can have this condition on your `template` task, and templates will be skipped for any servers whose site is NOT "newyork" or "paris".

```yaml
    - name: template file
      template:
        src: toto/toto.j2
        dest: "/tmp/toto_{{ item.value.name }}"
      when: item.value.site in ["newyork", "paris"]
      with_dict: "{{ server }}"
```